# How do I get responsive images to stay equivalent heights as they scale?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 right now on a website project. 
I am having problems using img-responsive to make my images responsive.

What I want is 4 images side by side in a container that are all the same height and scale together as the screen size changes.

Following the Bootstrap grid system, I have the images taking up a total of 12 columns.

1 = Leftmost image 2 = Second image 3 = Third image from left 4 = Rightmost image

1 -  3 cols, 960x640  2 = 2 columns, 640x640  3 = 4 columns, 1280x640 4 = 3 columns, 960x640

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="responsive" src="/image/1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img class="responsive" src="/image/2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="responsive" src="/image/3.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="responsive" src="/image/4.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make sure they are all the same height as they scale? Right now all images simply have img-responsive as a class, making their max-width 100%, height set on auto, and display as block.

CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: can u mention the original image dimensions?
perhaps the different column sizes are not proportionate to width's of the images for the same heights.
The best way is to give widths in proportionate percentages and height:auto to the images

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma yeah okay I just added those now! I think that might actually be the problem...

Comment: This website really helps. http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: If you don't care about IE<10, consider using the flexbox-based equal-height columns approach in this PR: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought of another, simpler way of doing this, when addressing another question... Just override the col-md-* padding by adding a custom class. No media query required.

**Example: http://www.bootply.com/utGXpeBgE2**

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 no-pad">
  <img ...
```

CSS

```
.no-pad{
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not displayed at full height when their widths are constricted by the next image. You need to add `position:absolute` to get around this. However that causes a problem when screen below the col-md threshold (992px), so only add it when above it, by way of @media query

```
@media(min-width:992px){
  .img-responsive{
      position:absolute;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/960x640/eee">
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/640x640/ddd">
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1280x640/eee">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-3">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/960x640/ddd">
   </div>
```

See example: http://www.bootply.com/11BDvXAx9y